# Tento instalar o React Navigation e me retorna um erro de permissão negada

Tags: android, react-native

Eu tentei instalar o módulo React Navigation no meu projeto com o seguinte comando:

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Mas me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git /home/diegomng/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ad6cfd48
npm ERR! /home/diegomng/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ad6cfd48/.git: Permissão negada
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/diegomng/.npm/_logs/2018-04-03T16_31_55_746Z-debug.log
```

Minha versão do NodeJS: v9.6.1

NPM: 5.8.0

Yarn: 0.22

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.54.0

Comment: Já tentou instalar usando ` sudo npm install --save react-navigation`?

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema não está no React e sim com gerenciador de pacotes.

Tente usar o `yarn`, já tive esse problema e com yarn é bem tranquilo.

Answer (score 0):

Também tive esse problema com alguns pacotes do React.
Caso você esteja usando o terminal de comandos da sua máquina, tente usar o terminal do Git.

Instale o [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/) apropriado para o seu SO. Depois disso, você terá o Git CMD. Através dele muitos erros como este podem ser evitados.